# Ckeditor Subscript and Superscript buttons

Tags: civimail, ckeditor

I have manually edited the ckeditor config file: packages/ckeditor/config.js to enable the Subscript and Superscript buttons by commenting out this line //config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript

this is working correctly in my local environment but when i deploy it on production, the Subscript and Superscript buttons  are not available.

clearing cache (drush cc all, /civicrm/clearcache, browser cache) doesn't help, the only difference between my local and production is https.

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Once you upgrade to 4.7 it will be super easy due to the new configurator UI.

See https://civicrm.org/blogs/colemanw/big-changes-wysiwyg-editing-47

4.7 is now [available for beta testing](https://civicrm.org/blogs/seamuslee/let-the-47-beta-testing-begin), be sure to give it a try :)

Comment: Many thanks @Coleman, this has been resolved in production by cleaning varnish cache, Still testing 4.7 though :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answers to

[How do I override the default CKEditor configuration?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4523/how-do-i-override-the-default-ckeditor-configuration)

and

[Is there a way to enable or install the full version of CKEditor in CiviCRM 4.6.x?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/930/is-there-a-way-to-enable-or-install-the-full-version-of-ckeditor-in-civicrm-4-6)

Might be some help there.