# CKEditor not fully functional in CiviCRM 4.6.11

Tags: joomla, ckeditor

We are expecting the editor in CiviCRM to look like this: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Users_Guide/Interface/Toolbar

There is at least one row missing on the toolbar that we can see. Is there a way to fix this on CiviCRM 4.6(Joomla 3.4.8) or install CKEditor Premium?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at 
[Is there a way to enable or install the full version of CKEditor in CiviCRM 4.6.x?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/930/is-there-a-way-to-enable-or-install-the-full-version-of-ckeditor-in-civicrm-4-6)
as well as 
[Big Changes To WYSIWYG Editing In 4.7](https://civicrm.org/blogs/colemanw/big-changes-wysiwyg-editing-47)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work with Joomla.  It does with Drupal.  In the display preferences you can pick use Default Joomla editor.  Then on the Joolma side you can probably configure the editor with which toolbar options are available.  Some of them might not work as expected on the Civi side of things.

Answer (score 0):

We discovered the Joomla Editor ourselves and were using that with limited succsess. Of course now 4.7 is available hopefully this shouldn't be an issue anymore! :)